# circuit analysis basic question

Tags: circuit-analysis

All voltages are referenced to ground unless otherwise noted.

SW1 = CLOSED; VA =

[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: Since this is homework you need to show your work. Draw the equivalent circuit. There's a CircuitLab schematic button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 0):

If measurement section in Va has an infinite impedance then when switch SW1 is **closed**, then the equivalent circuit is

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhlEY9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

All current transfer from R1(zero ohm switch)  and **VA = 20**.

No current transfer from 6K and 10K branch. and voltage in all point of this branch is 20V.

EDIT:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiKPmL.png)</sup>

you can play with meter impedance and switch!

Comment: Alternatively, you can think of the 10k/6k resistors in parallel as one simple pullup resistor to 20V once the switch is closed.

Comment: Thank you, guys. I think I need to brush up basic circuit theory book again.